# Creating uniquely named dataframes from one larger dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

quite new to working with data frames and loops. Looking for answers to my query in either python or R. I have a data frame similar in structure to the one below.

```
        TP1.v1  | TP1.v2 | TP1.v3 | TP2.v1 | TP2.v2 | TP2.v3 |... TPn.v1
 Gene A|  7     |6       |7       |6       |4       |1       |... 9    
 Gene B|  3     |4       |4       |4       |5       |3       |... 3    
 Gene n|  6     |1       |1       |5       |7       |7       |... 8
```

I would like to create a new data frame for all the TP1s, TP2s and so on. Each TP (time point) has 3 columns associated with it. I would also ideally like to use a loop to do this as I have multiple files with similar structures. Finally, I would like the loop to give each of the new data frames a new and unique name.

I have been able to do this task in R without the use of loops. Simply using basic functions repeatedly to manipulate the data frame. But this is quite slow and laborious so would like to do this in a loop.

The ideal output would be n number of uniquely named dataframes, each with 3 columns, and each retaining the row names and col names from the original data frame.

Below I have added output from dput(head(df)) from R.

```
structure(list(D1.log2fc = c(-0.453086, -0.1828075, 0.105551500000001, 
0.368134000000001, 0.194800000000001, -0.327664499999999), D1.AveExp = c(4.9001385, 
5.59887075, 9.35607416666667, 9.466082, 9.28132575, 5.43070783333333    
), D1.adjPval = c(0.158162310733078, 0.680539779380169, 0.798318133631351, 
0.368809197240543, 0.588741274410125, 0.363696882398466), D3.log2fc = c(-0.5979695, 
-0.510921500000001, 0.544158999999999, 0.354766, 0.631701999999999, 
-0.365363499999998), D3.AveExp = c(4.9001385, 5.59887075, 9.35607416666667, 
9.466082, 9.28132575, 5.43070783333333), D3.adjPval =  c(0.0354796268783931, 
0.104426887750224, 0.0342979093938487, 0.318289098430963, 0.0318404713171763, 
0.231275103023615), D6.log2fc = c(-0.349413, -0.854375500000001, 
0.7416965, 0.5901225, 0.821465500000002, -0.578061499999999), 
D6.AveExp = c(4.9001385, 5.59887075, 9.35607416666667, 9.466082, 
9.28132575, 5.43070783333333), D6.adjPval = c(0.151181193217808, 
0.00788722811936, 0.00487109163210043, 0.0635131764099792, 
0.00547087529420614, 0.0423872835135151), D10.log2fc =      c(-0.528707499999999, 
-0.431807000000002, 0.454508000000001, 0.628860999999999, 
0.379918500000002, -0.195571999999999), D10.AveExp = c(4.9001385, 
5.59887075, 9.35607416666667, 9.466082, 9.28132575, 5.43070783333333
), D10.adjPval = c(0.0360033103086792, 0.125511404231851, 
0.0445352483558512, 0.0499786423872913, 0.126969394135026, 
0.517590415583245), D14.log2fc = c(-0.517372, -0.379950000000001, 
0.596869, 0.7255935, 0.6545535, -0.205755499999999), D14.AveExp = c(4.9001385, 
5.59887075, 9.35607416666667, 9.466082, 9.28132575, 5.43070783333333
), D14.adjPval = c(0.039311630129941, 0.172677856404577, 
0.0124695746689562, 0.0265985268105264, 0.0152333310246979, 
0.452405710914221)), row.names = c("hsa-let-7a-2", "hsa-let-7b", 
"hsa-let-7d", "hsa-let-7e", "hsa-let-7f", "hsa-let-7f1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible dataset using `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: I've added this information to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to do this in `R`

```
# assuming you know the prefix and how many time points you have (e.g. D and 5)
tp <- c(1, 3, 6, 10, 14)
prefix <- "D"

# for loop
for (i in tp) {
  common <- paste0(prefix, i) # create common name e.g. D1, D3, D6 etc.
  # assign columns to its unique df
  assign(common, df[, grep(paste0(common, "\\."), colnames(df), ignore.case = T)])
}

# using lapply (could be a bit faster than for loop)
lapply(tp, function(i) {
  common <- paste0(prefix, i) # create common name e.g. D1, D3, D6 etc.
  # assign columns to its unique df
  assign(common, df[, grep(paste0(common, "\\."), colnames(df), ignore.case = T)], envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

Edit: `lapply` is actually significantly faster than `for` loop. Here are `microbenchmark` results

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
    for.loop 3045.718 3167.800 3549.2943 3284.6260 3424.485 79971.27  1000
 lapply.call  170.647  184.086  204.4465  192.4345  200.538  4123.52  1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by uniquely named DataFrames. This will create a dictionary holding each of the DataFrames. Hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,3*10), 
                  columns = ['TP%d.v%d'%(i, j) for i in range(1,11) for j in range(1,4)])

# Construct dictionary:
dd = {}
for name in df.columns.str.split('.').str[0].unique():
    dd[name] = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith(name)]].copy()
```

If you feel like working with multiindexed DataFrames instead. The following solution will simply redefine the columns of your current DataFrame. Working with these can be a bit more convoluted, but much more efficient:

```
# MultiIndex Solution
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
```